# A function that is a tight and smooth estimation of the nth prime function?

Tags: prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Does it exist a given explicit function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ such that forall N  big enough $\exists m,n\in\mathbb N: m,n>N \wedge f(m)\leq p_m\wedge f(n)\geq p_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal answer to your question: $f(x)=p_{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ works. But I think you want something stronger than merely being "explicit", more like a finite-length formula over well-known functions.

Littlewood proved in 1914 that for all $N$ there are $n,m>N$ such that
$$
\operatorname{li}(m)\le\pi(m)\ \vee\ \operatorname{li}(n)\ge\pi(n).
$$
The usual citation is [1] though I have not read the paper (it is in French). It is likely that for all $N$ there are $n,m>N$ such that
$$
¿\qquad\operatorname{li}^{-1}(p_m)\le m\ \vee\ \operatorname{li}^{-1}(p_n)\ge p\qquad?
$$
but I cannot immediately prove this.

[1] J. E. Littlewood, Sur la distribution des nombres premiers, *Comptes Rendus* **158** (1914), pp. 1869-1872.

Comment: It may be that I don't understand your notation well. I think Littlewood's paper proves something stronger--the inequalities are strict and the theorem guarantees a difference that depends explicitly on x (your m,n). Sidestepping the French, the claim is Littlewood's eq. (3). I realize this is not the main point of your answer...